# How just send messages to other clients?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a question with java sockets. My code sends messages to all clients, including sending. I want him to send only for other clients How can I do this? I test using `telnet 127.0.0.1 2015` command in the terminal.

Client

```
package socket;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Clientes implements Runnable {

    public Socket cliente;

    public Clientes(Socket cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(cliente.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.write("---Seja Bem Vindo---\n");
            out.flush();

            System.out.println("Nova conexao: "
                    + this.cliente.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());

            while (true) {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        cliente.getInputStream()));
                String veioDoCliente = in.readLine();

                if(veioDoCliente.equalsIgnoreCase("SAIR")){
                    cliente.close();
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("MSG vinda do cliente " + veioDoCliente);

                for (Clientes writer : Servidor.clientes) {
                    PrintWriter out2 = new PrintWriter(writer.cliente.getOutputStream(), true);
                    out2.write("teste:"+veioDoCliente+"\n");
                    out2.flush();

                }


                //s.close();
                 //this.cliente.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Server

```
package socket;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Servidor {
    public Socket cliente;

    public Servidor(Socket cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }


    public static List<Clientes> clientes = new ArrayList<Clientes>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(2015);

        System.out.println("Esperando alguem se conectar...");

        while (true) {
            Socket cliente = servidor.accept();

            Clientes tratamento = new Clientes(cliente);

            clientes.add(tratamento);

            Thread t = new Thread(tratamento);
            t.start();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing where your server is handling the code coming in, so I'm shooting in the dark.

Basically, when your data comes in, you see which client it originated from and then check in your loop to see if that client matches the current client. If no match, then send the data out.

If not possible any other way, you will need to give each client and ID and it will send the data with the ID string, but I'm sure that you can keep track of your clients using the socket.